# Why use dependency injection for Request object vs request() helper in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, dependency-injection, laravel-5.6

Is there any benefit to injecting the Request object into your controller method like this:

```
use Request;

class WidgetController
{
  public function create(Request $request)
  {
    $name = $request->input('name');
  }
}
```

Versus eliminating the use statement and object injection and simply using the helper:

```
class WidgetController
{
  public function create()
  {
    $name = request('name');
  }
}
```

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/facades#facades-vs-dependency-injection

Comment: Thanks @devon, between that section you linked to and the Facades vs Helpers section just below, it's clearly laid out, guess I didn't search the docs well enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The primary reason to use injection is because of testing. If you use request() then you need to initialize the Laravel app since request() calls app('request'). If app('request') is not initialized then your tests will generate an error.

When you use injection you pass on the Request object to the method. This means that during testing you can create your own "dummy" request and pass that on to the method without having to initialize app(). Then you can test the method and only the method without and dependencies to anything else.

Answer (score 7):

The `request` helper is just a shortcut to `Request::input('name')`. The code for the request helper is defined like this [request helper](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/e32e92706fe3ba26aef496d23a452750a4653725/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L545)

```
app('request')->input($key, $default);
```

The app is the Container that manages the Dependency injection of Laravel. It will resolve the dependency that correspond to the name `request` which is an instance of `Illuminate\Http\Request` and call on it the method `input` passing the name of the key you want to retrieve.

There is really no difference, one is a shortcut of the other.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, code-styling and readability. The first one is way more readable. Second thing from top of my mind is that, if you use `request()` helper, you can not validate the request.

Let's say your request must contain a parameter `title` and `body`. If the parameter is not there, it should never reach that endpoint. Using the `helper()`, there is not way to do it. While, using the first method, there is really convenient way of doing that.

```
class StoreRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'title' => 'required',
            'body' => 'sometimes'
        ];
    }
}
```

And than just:

```
use StoreRequest;

class WidgetController
{
  public function create(StoreRequest $request)
  {
    $name = $request->input('name');
  }
}
```

Comment: You brought in a whole other component here, form requests.  You can definitely still have validation rules without form request classes.

Comment: You can actually validate like this request()->validate(['name' => ['required', 'string']]);  I see the point for the validation technique you used though.

Comment: You can also validate by calling the method `make` on the `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator` facade like this `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), ['t' => 'required']);`

Comment: @YvesKipondo just take a look at what you wrote, than take a look at my approach, and tell me which one is more readable. It's not only to make it work, you should also make it readable. And while you can validate with `make`, he was only asking the difference between `request()` vs dependency injection

Comment: It isn't about readability when you specify the qualified class name any one who open you file will know that the method that you're calling is define in some `Request` class but when you call `request` He will go up and looking in your file He won't find the definition of that method directly unless He is knows the way laravel will handle that

Answer (score 0):

Might be late but useful information about using request() helper is that you don't need to pass request object to your business logic classes.

For instance:

```
User.php
-----------------------------------------------
...
protected $helper;

public function __construct(FileHelper $helper) {
    $this->helper = $helper

public function uploadFile() {
    $file = $this->helper->insertFile();
}
...
-----------------------------------------------


FileHelper.php
-----------------------------------------------
...

public function insertFile() {
    $file = request()->file('filename');
    // ur code 

}
...
-----------------------------------------------
```

See that you don't need to pass $request to your insertFile since the request helper globally injected into your app.

Comment: I like this limitation as it deters me from passing the request object around. I think it's better to pass the service/business logic layer only the data that it needs - in your example you'd pass `$request->file('filename')` to `insertFile()`.